# Having problem with using Replace in Do-loop

Tags: replacement, summation

I am trying to set to zero some expression in a very long summation in mathematica. So I have decided to use a do loop along with a the replace operator over all indices I want to remove (actually indices such as [-i, 0], [0,0] and [i, 0]).

```
Do[
    Cor = Cor /. {q[i, 0] -> 0}
 , {i, 0, ndof1}]
Cor
```

with Cor is something like

```
Cor = - Sum[ (eps[j, k]*q[j, k]     +      
      q[j, k]*abs (q[j, k])^(sig) - 
      w*(q[j - 1, k] + q[j + 1, k] + q[j, k - 1] + q[j, k + 1]) )^2
    , {j, 0, ndof1}, {k , 0, ndof2}]
```

As a result, I am getting something with

```
/. 0 /. 0 /. 0 /. 0 /. 0 /. 0 /. 0 /. 0 /. 0 /. 0 /. 0
```

at the end on which I can't perform further operation like derivative for instance.

Please can someone help. I am struggling with this problem in many of my codes so that I get a proper expression at the end.

Comment: can you explicitly define the variable `q` like `Do[q[i,0]=0, {i, 0, ndof1}]`? and then evaluate `Cor`?

Comment: You can use `rep = Table[q[i, 0] -> 0, {i, 0, n1}]` and then `cor /. rep`

Comment: Thanks you, I have tried it in many cases it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ReplaceAll` on the expression `Cor` to achieve your goal.

Let's try a test case

```
ndof1 = 2;
ndof2 = 1;
sig = 2;
```

Evaluate `Cor`

```
Cor = -Sum[(eps[j, k]*q[j, k] + q[j, k] abs (q[j, k])^(sig) -
       w*(q[j - 1, k] + q[j + 1, k] + q[j, k - 1] + 
         q[j, k + 1]))^2, {j, 0, ndof1}, {k, 0, ndof2}]

(* -(eps[0, 0] q[0, 0] + abs q[0, 0]^3 - 
    w (q[-1, 0] + q[0, -1] + q[0, 1] + q[1, 0]))^2 - (eps[0, 1] q[0, 
     1] + abs q[0, 1]^3 - 
   w (q[-1, 1] + q[0, 0] + q[0, 2] + q[1, 1]))^2 - (eps[1, 0] q[1, 
     0] + abs q[1, 0]^3 - 
   w (q[0, 0] + q[1, -1] + q[1, 1] + q[2, 0]))^2 - (eps[1, 1] q[1, 
     1] + abs q[1, 1]^3 - 
   w (q[0, 1] + q[1, 0] + q[1, 2] + q[2, 1]))^2 - (eps[2, 0] q[2, 0] +
    abs q[2, 0]^3 - 
   w (q[1, 0] + q[2, -1] + q[2, 1] + q[3, 0]))^2 - (eps[2, 1] q[2, 
     1] + abs q[2, 1]^3 - w (q[1, 1] + q[2, 0] + q[2, 2] + q[3, 1]))^2 *)
```

Use `ReplaceAll` on the `Cor` expression

```
corNew = Cor /. q[_, 0] -> 0

(* -w^2 (q[0, -1] + q[0, 1])^2 - 
 w^2 (q[1, -1] + q[1, 1])^2 - (eps[0, 1] q[0, 1] + abs q[0, 1]^3 - 
   w (q[-1, 1] + q[0, 2] + q[1, 1]))^2 - 
 w^2 (q[2, -1] + q[2, 1])^2 - (eps[1, 1] q[1, 1] + abs q[1, 1]^3 - 
   w (q[0, 1] + q[1, 2] + q[2, 1]))^2 - (eps[2, 1] q[2, 1] + 
   abs q[2, 1]^3 - w (q[1, 1] + q[2, 2] + q[3, 1]))^2 *)
```

Comment: This also works fine. Thanks guys.